# Array.prototype.slice.call returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am beginner at Javascript. I need to store the JSON request data to sub document in mongo db database. The approach that I have thought of is to convert the JSON request to array & then use $push method to pass the array to the sub document. When I send request to route using Postman Array.prototype.slice.call returns the [] 'empty array'.

Kindly let me know what could be the probable reason. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

```
// @route    PUT api/prescription/:patientId
// @desc     Add prescription
// @access   Private

router.post('/:patientId',auth,adminDocguard, async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.prescription);

    var newPrescription = Array.prototype.slice.call(req.body.prescription);

    console.log(newPrescription)
    try {
        const patient_profile = await Patient.findOneAndUpdate(

            {patientId:req.params.patientId},
            {"$push":{"prescription":newPrescription}},
            {"upsert":true,"new":true}

          );
          await patient_profile.save();
          res.json(patient_profile);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

JSON request using postman:

```
 {
    "prescription":{
    "1":{"mediaction": "Crocin456",
    "dosage": "200"
    },
    "2":{"mediaction": "Crocin123",
    "dosage": "200"
    }
    }

}
```

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
const config =require('config');
const db=config.get('mongoURI');

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(db);

autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

const PatientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    phonenumber:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    slider_1:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    slider_2:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    slider_3:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    prescription:[
        {
            mediaction:{
                type:String
            },
            dosage:{
                type:Number
            },
            morning:{
                type:Number
            },
            evening:{
                type:Number
            }
        }
    ]

});
PatientSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
  model:'Patient',
   field:'patientId',
   startAt:1,
   incrementBy:1
});

module.exports=Patient=mongoose.model('patient',PatientSchema);
```

Comment: You're trying to use `.slice()` on something that is not an array, or anything like an array; it's a plain object.

Comment: Hi Pointy..Thanks for your input. Can you please help me convert the JSON request to Array?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "convert to an Array".  What exactly do you expect the array to contain?

Comment: My objective is to insert multiple subdocuments to Mongo Db collection using "{"$push":{"prescription":newPrescription}} " $push function. For which I am trying to convert the request to array which can be stored in the newPrescription.

Comment: Right but you have not described what you expect the array to look like. Objects have property names and values; arrays just have values.

Comment: Hi pointy.. Array should look something like this: 
         [  { "_id": "5d0dc301f3232a26a416c332",
            "mediaction": "Crocin",
            "dosage": 200
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d0eeb1871a2b45d30932822",
            "mediaction": "Crocin456",
            "dosage": 200
        }]

Comment: Hi Pointy..My sincere apologies if I am being not clear. I am trying to enter multiple prescriptions to the patient schema in a  single request. I am not sure whether the approach I am using is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert your prescription object into an array, you should specify what is the shape of every object in the newly created array.
Since the prescriptions in the object have a serial id, I would probably convert ii in something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "mediaction": "Crocin456",
    "dosage": "200"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "mediaction": "Crocin123",
    "dosage": "200"
  }
]
```

To apply this transformation, you can simply do it in with this code:

```
const { prescription } = req.body;
const prescriptionArray = Object.keys(prescription).map(id => ({
  id,
  ...prescription[id]
}))
```